# how to upload a zip file under apache ode?

Tags: java, web-services, soa, axis, bpel

I'm in Apache Ode and when i want to upload the zip file (the zip file is just the helloWorld example from the ODE website in a zip) i'm getting this error:

```
Invocation of operation deploy failed: org.apache.ode.axis2.OdeFault: The deployment doesn't appear to contain a
deployment descriptor in its root directory named deploy.xml, aborting.
```

Comment: Please post the structure of your zip file here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you extract the zip file, it should be having the following structure.

```
.
|-- deploy.xml
|-- HelloWorld2.bpel
|-- HelloWorld2.wsdl
`-- test.properties
```

Thanks